# Co- browsing implementation in java

Tags: java

Co-Browsing in the context of web browsing, is the joint navigation through the Internet by two or more people accessing the same web pages at the same time.

for more information please have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobrowsing

here are some paid alternatives which does this

http://www.livelook.com/co_browsing.asp

http://www.unblu.com/

any help regarding what technology is being used to implement this or technical specifications ?

i am trying to implement co-browsing using java, has any one have prior experience with that if its possible or any existing java library doing the same?

if there is not any solution what approach should i use to implement this.

Comment: Your question is very broad, and you don't even define co-browsing. What does it mean?

Comment: added wikipedia link just to give an idea about co-browsing

Comment: And now, do you have better idea ? I'm looking for the same kind of information. I found out that some are using Node.js as the backend, but this did not tell me how to develop it on the client side

Comment: I also found this: http://www2009.eprints.org/95/1/p941.pdf which is a bit too scholar but could help to have a better understanding of some technics.

Comment: In this link: http://techcrunch.com/2011/09/13/goinstant-is-browser-sharing-with-no-downloads/ they mention that they use:  Node.js, Socket.io and Redis