# Implement collaborative browsing using opensource technologies?

Tags: javascript, php, html, servlets, webrtc

Cobrowsing/collaborative browsing -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobrowsing

I am trying to implement Cobrowsing from scratch into my web application.
My application is based on PHP.

I have already tried [togather.js](https://togetherjs.com/), but it doesn't mimic the scroll and click actions and lacks community support.

No Information is available on the architecture of developing a co-browsing enabled app on the internet and all supports are paid.

I have found the following links, but I have no knowledge of java. 
1)http://www.servletsuite.com/servlets/cobrowse.htm
2)[Co- browsing implementation in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254758/co-browsing-implementation-in-java)
3)[Collaborative Browsing using HTML5 and websockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22244364/collaborative-browsing-using-html5-and-websockets)

I wanted to know, how Cobrowsing works internally. Like what data is shared between the users, how sessions are in sync, can co-browsing be achieved without java?.

Any help is deeply appreciated.

One Approach I can Think of is:

1. Monitor DOM changing events and cursor position.
2. Sending the event data along with cursor position using RTCDataChannel API(WebRTC)
3. Recreate event using Js and event data.

I have successfully established the connection using RTCDataChannel, But I have just come to realize that I can't use JS event object(click event object) from one peer to recreate event at another peer.

Any suggestions what data I need to send to construct Cobrowsing?

Comment: Interesting project. If I was making this, I'd use Javascript to capture what each user is doing and send an Ajax request every few seconds to update a database. Can get pretty complex tho, especially since you'll need to account for each different users page resolution

Comment: I am thinking of monitoring any DOM change/event and sending the event data along with cursor position using RTCDataChannel API. At other end fire the same event using JS. Any suggestions?

Comment: RTC looks good however, I've never used it. The API looks pretty neat. I think this is the way to go to achieve this project.

Comment: The only problem I really see with the RTCDataChannel is that if you won't be able to send historic data. If person A has started typing in a chatbox, then midway thru typing person B joins, they will only see half of the data inputted.

Comment: Yes, that would be an issue. Maybe I could impose some sort of restriction on input fields. I will think it through.